# How would you phrase a question to a person that regressed spacetimewise?

Tags: past-tense, future, future-in-past

This is quite confusing.

Let's say, there's this person who came back in time to their original state in that particular moment. So, they know exactly how things play out in their timeline point.

How would you ask a question about their timeline?

For example, you'd like to ask when the war breaks out. Relative to them, that is an event that happened in the past, but is yet to happen for you.

I reckon, I'd ask such a question thusly: "hey, so when would the war break out?"

Comment: In your future: "When will war break out?" In their past: "When did war break out?" For some reason, I omitted the (definite) article when phrasing it... and suggest "In what year does the war happen?" which suits both parties' time line.

Comment: This is not a situation that most people have experienced, and so there are no conventions to guide us through it.  I expect a fair amount of confusion and misunderstanding.

Comment: Interesting, but without any examples in the real world, it's going to be a matter of opinion. Cases where a writer invented a usage (that hasn't caught on more widely) are also considered off-topic here, but might fit on Literature SE, or in this case SF and Fantasy SE.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't resist.

From a [collection of "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" quotations](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eparam/quotes/guide.html) (by Douglas Adams, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)) [some typos corrected]:

> The major problem [with time travel] is simply one of grammar, and the main work to consult in this matter is Dr. Dan Streetmentioner's *Time Traveler's Handbook of 1001 Tense Formations*. It will tell you, for instance, how to describe something that was about to happen to you in the past before you avoided it by time-jumping forward two days in order to avoid it. The event will be described differently according to whether you are talking about it from the standpoint of your own natural time, from a time in the further future, or a time in the further past and is further complicated by the possibility of conducting conversations while you are actually traveling from one time to another with the intention of becoming your own mother or father.

> Most readers get as far as the Future Semiconditionally Modified Subinverted Plagal Past Subjunctive Intentional before giving up; and in fact in later editions of the book all pages beyond this point have been left blank to save on printing costs.

> The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy skips lightly over this tangle of academic abstraction, pausing only to note that the term "Future Perfect" has been abandoned since it was discovered not to be.